# Loop with varying interval

Tags: python, discord.py

I have to perform a loop with an interval based on how many users sign up. User can sign up during the loop which effects the interval duration.

I tried using the `@task.loop()` decorator from the **discord.ext** library but couldn't get it to work. As the **discord.ext** library contains methods to do loops, I would prefer to use it. However, I don't know if that is possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to tell what have you tried

Comment: based on the very little information you gave us, you can set an interval using a for loop with a third object in your for statement.

It can be used like this:

```for x in range(start, end, interval)```

Answer (score 1):

I found the `change_interval` method. I could then change the interval each time a user signs up. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval